# WPF Ribbon steals TAB

Tags: wpf, focus, ribbon

I have a simple WPF application with Ribbon and few controls. Unfortunately when pressing TAB key to change focus, Ribbon somehow manages looping only within itself, other controls don't get a chance...

This is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="136" />
  <RowDefinition Height="175*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<my:Ribbon HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="ribbon1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <my:RibbonTab Header="Ribbon">
    <my:RibbonGroup>
      <my:RibbonComboBox Label="ComboBox" Name="ribbonComboBox1">
        <my:RibbonGallery MaxColumnCount="1">
          <my:RibbonGalleryCategory>
            <my:RibbonGalleryItem Content="An item" />
          </my:RibbonGalleryCategory>
        </my:RibbonGallery>
      </my:RibbonComboBox>
    </my:RibbonGroup>
  </my:RibbonTab>
</my:Ribbon>
<TextBox TabIndex="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,19,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
<TextBox TabIndex="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,48,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Let me answer myself. For my purposes it's OK to NOT to use TAB for Ribbon. For Ribbon I can use KeyTip(s), so basically I have just added Focusable="False" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" into ribbon definition. So the whole code could look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="136" />
      <RowDefinition Height="175*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <my:Ribbon Focusable="False" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="ribbon1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <my:RibbonTab Header="Ribbon" KeyTip="R">
        <my:RibbonGroup>
          <my:RibbonComboBox KeyTip="C" Label="ComboBox" Name="ribbonComboBox1">
            <my:RibbonGallery MaxColumnCount="1">
              <my:RibbonGalleryCategory>
                <my:RibbonGalleryItem Content="An item" />
              </my:RibbonGalleryCategory>
            </my:RibbonGallery>
          </my:RibbonComboBox>
        </my:RibbonGroup>
      </my:RibbonTab>
    </my:Ribbon>
    <TextBox TabIndex="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,19,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <TextBox TabIndex="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,48,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Row="1" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" does it for me, using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.dll